# Share internet from android to PC through usb and wifi

Tags: android, hotspot

I got this rly annoying problem when sharing the internet-connection from my andorid phone to my PC, Laptop & Raspberry pi. I connected my phone to my PC with a usb-cable to share internet since my PC has no wifi-adapter and my laptop and raspberry pi through the wifi-hotspot. I want to be able to ssh to my raspberry pi from my PC, but i cant. The raspberry get's a different ip than my PC localy.

RaspPI = 192.168.43.xxx

PC = 192.168.42.xxx

is there a way to get them both on the same subnet so i can connect to the Pi localy? My android phone is blocking all incoming traffic so i cant ssh my public ip

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution would be on the phone's side, and questions about android are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phone is not a router so it won't allow you to connect the two devices like that, and the phone by design creates one subnet for wi-fi hosts and one subnet for tethered hosts. You can either connect your PC directly to the Raspberry Pi with an ethernet cable and setup a seperate subnet with no default gateway (since there's no internet connectivity) on both devices for that wired connection, or setup your Raspberry Pi as a router sharing the wireless network with any devices connected to the LAN port, with your PC connected by patch cable and getting DHCP from the Pi.